# How can I compute the expected value of X squared given X higher than Y?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Good morning,

How can I compute $\mathbb E[X^2|X>Y] $ given X and Y as continuous random variable.
$X$ and $Y$ follows the same distribution, in fact $Y=F^{(-1)}(c)$ where c is a given number.

I know that:
$\mathbb E[X|X>Y]=\frac{1}{P(X>Y)}\int_{Y}^{+\infty} x\cdot f(x) \cdot dx =\frac{1}{P(X>Y)}\int_{F(Y)}^{F(+\infty)} F^{-1}(t) \cdot dt$

Given the function $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(u)du$.

However I do not know how I could compute $\mathbb E[X^2|X>Y] $ .
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: Y follows the same distribution as X, you can imagine X as $Y=F^{(-1)}(c)$ where c is a number decided in advance.

Comment: Your $Y$ is not random. It is a  fixed real number. That should make your computation very simple.

Comment: May I ask you if it could be something like $\frac{1}{P(X>Y)}\int_{Y}^{+\infty}x^2f(x)dx$?
If this is true, does it means that $\mathbb{E}[X^n|X>Y]=\frac{1}{P(X>Y)}\int_{Y}^{+\infty}x^nf(x)dx$?

Comment: Yes, that is true for any $n$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I just got confused thinkin $Y$ as a random variable and not as a fixed number. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you know, could you let me know how I should do in case Y is a random variable indipendent from X? Just for curiosity

Answer (score 1):

[This answer is in response to OP's comment above].

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent with densities $f$ and $g$ then $E(X^{2}|X>Y)=\frac {\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \int_{y} ^{\infty} x^{2}f(x)g(y)dxdy} {\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty}\int_{y} ^{\infty} f(x)g(y)dxdy} $

Comment: ... and as also said in the comments, if $Y$ is a constant $y$ then this reduces to $E(X^{2}|X>y)=\dfrac {\int_{y} ^{\infty} x^{2}f(x)\,dx} {\int_{y} ^{\infty} f(x)\,dx}=\dfrac {\int_{y} ^{\infty} x^{2}f(x)\,dx} {\mathbb P(X>y)}$